# How can i stop Javascript animated text from repeating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this code for showing up these letters and words one by one, but my problem is that the code is still repeating, can someone help me to know how to stop it?

```html
 <div id="changeText"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var text = ["|", "W|", "We|", "Wel|", "Welc|", "Welco|", "Welcom|", "Welcome|", "Welcome |", "Welcome t|", "Welcome to|", "Welcome to |", "Welcome to K|", "Welcome to Ka|", "Welcome to Kar|", "Welcome to Karl|", "Welcome to Karla|", "Welcome to Karla'|", "Welcome to Karla's|", "Welcome to Karla's |", "Welcome to Karla's T|", "Welcome to Karla's Tr|", "Welcome to Karla's Tra|", "Welcome to Karla's Trad|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradi|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradin|", "Welcome to Karla's Trading|", "Welcome to Karla's Trading", "Welcome to Karla's Trading|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradin|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradi|", "Welcome to Karla's Trad|", "Welcome to Karla's Tra|", "Welcome to Karla's Tr|", "Welcome to Karla's T|", "Welcome to Karla's |", "Welcome to Karla's|", "Welcome to Karla'|", "Welcome to Karla|", "Welcome to Karl|", "Welcome to Kar|", "Welcome to Ka|", "Welcome to K|", "Welcome to |", "Welcome t|", "Welcome |", "Welcome|", "Welcom|", "Welco|", "Welc|", "Wel|", "We|", "W|", "|"];
    var counter = 0;
    var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
    setInterval(change, 250);
    function change() {
     elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
        counter++;
        if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
    }


    </script>
```

Comment: you can use clearInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this version, `change` is only called again if there are still remaining elements in `text`.

```html
<div id="changeText"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var text = ["|", "W|", "We|", "Wel|", "Welc|", "Welco|", "Welcom|", "Welcome|", "Welcome |", "Welcome t|", "Welcome to|", "Welcome to |", "Welcome to K|", "Welcome to Ka|", "Welcome to Kar|", "Welcome to Karl|", "Welcome to Karla|", "Welcome to Karla'|", "Welcome to Karla's|", "Welcome to Karla's |", "Welcome to Karla's T|", "Welcome to Karla's Tr|", "Welcome to Karla's Tra|", "Welcome to Karla's Trad|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradi|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradin|", "Welcome to Karla's Trading|", "Welcome to Karla's Trading", "Welcome to Karla's Trading|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradin|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradi|", "Welcome to Karla's Trad|", "Welcome to Karla's Tra|", "Welcome to Karla's Tr|", "Welcome to Karla's T|", "Welcome to Karla's |", "Welcome to Karla's|", "Welcome to Karla'|", "Welcome to Karla|", "Welcome to Karl|", "Welcome to Kar|", "Welcome to Ka|", "Welcome to K|", "Welcome to |", "Welcome t|", "Welcome |", "Welcome|", "Welcom|", "Welco|", "Welc|", "Wel|", "We|", "W|", "|"];
    var counter = 0;
    var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
    function change() {
        elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
        counter++;
        if (counter < text.length) {
            setTimeout(change, 250);
        }
    }
    change();
</script>
```

BTW, here's a way to avoid having to type `"W|"`, `"We|"`, etc. and make the code more reusable:

```html
<div id="changeText"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function animate(elem, text) {
        var counter = 0;
        function change() {
            var length = counter;
            if (length > text.length) {
                length = 2 * text.length - counter;
            }
            elem.innerHTML = text.substring(0, length) + "|";
            counter++;
            if (counter <= 2 * text.length) {
                setTimeout(change, 250);
            }
        }
        change();
    }
    animate(document.getElementById("changeText"), "Welcome to Karla's Trading");
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

It repeats because you set the counter to 0. See what happens when I comment that away.

```html
 <div id="changeText"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var text = ["|", "W|", "We|", "Wel|", "Welc|", "Welco|", "Welcom|", "Welcome|", "Welcome |", "Welcome t|", "Welcome to|", "Welcome to |", "Welcome to K|", "Welcome to Ka|", "Welcome to Kar|", "Welcome to Karl|", "Welcome to Karla|", "Welcome to Karla'|", "Welcome to Karla's|", "Welcome to Karla's |", "Welcome to Karla's T|", "Welcome to Karla's Tr|", "Welcome to Karla's Tra|", "Welcome to Karla's Trad|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradi|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradin|", "Welcome to Karla's Trading|", "Welcome to Karla's Trading", "Welcome to Karla's Trading|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradin|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradi|", "Welcome to Karla's Trad|", "Welcome to Karla's Tra|", "Welcome to Karla's Tr|", "Welcome to Karla's T|", "Welcome to Karla's |", "Welcome to Karla's|", "Welcome to Karla'|", "Welcome to Karla|", "Welcome to Karl|", "Welcome to Kar|", "Welcome to Ka|", "Welcome to K|", "Welcome to |", "Welcome t|", "Welcome |", "Welcome|", "Welcom|", "Welco|", "Welc|", "Wel|", "We|", "W|", "|"];
    var counter = 0;
    var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
    setInterval(change, 250);
    function change() {
     elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
        counter++;
        if(counter >= text.length) { /* counter = 0;*/ }
    }


    </script>
```

Now you'll get the result saying that it is 'undefined'. Clearly not what you want either. The correct way of stopping this is to cancel the interval when the animation has finished.

```html
 <div id="changeText"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var text = ["|", "W|", "We|", "Wel|", "Welc|", "Welco|", "Welcom|", "Welcome|", "Welcome |", "Welcome t|", "Welcome to|", "Welcome to |", "Welcome to K|", "Welcome to Ka|", "Welcome to Kar|", "Welcome to Karl|", "Welcome to Karla|", "Welcome to Karla'|", "Welcome to Karla's|", "Welcome to Karla's |", "Welcome to Karla's T|", "Welcome to Karla's Tr|", "Welcome to Karla's Tra|", "Welcome to Karla's Trad|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradi|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradin|", "Welcome to Karla's Trading|", "Welcome to Karla's Trading", "Welcome to Karla's Trading|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradin|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradi|", "Welcome to Karla's Trad|", "Welcome to Karla's Tra|", "Welcome to Karla's Tr|", "Welcome to Karla's T|", "Welcome to Karla's |", "Welcome to Karla's|", "Welcome to Karla'|", "Welcome to Karla|", "Welcome to Karl|", "Welcome to Kar|", "Welcome to Ka|", "Welcome to K|", "Welcome to |", "Welcome t|", "Welcome |", "Welcome|", "Welcom|", "Welco|", "Welc|", "Wel|", "We|", "W|", "|"];
    var counter = 0;
    var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
    var animation = setInterval(change, 250);
    function change() {
     elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
        counter++;
        if(counter >= text.length) { 
              clearInterval(animation); // stop the animation
           }
    }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to clear **setInterval** after done:

```html
<div id="changeText"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var text = ["|", "W|", "We|", "Wel|", "Welc|", "Welco|", "Welcom|", "Welcome|", "Welcome |", "Welcome t|", "Welcome to|", "Welcome to |", "Welcome to K|", "Welcome to Ka|", "Welcome to Kar|", "Welcome to Karl|", "Welcome to Karla|", "Welcome to Karla'|", "Welcome to Karla's|", "Welcome to Karla's |", "Welcome to Karla's T|", "Welcome to Karla's Tr|", "Welcome to Karla's Tra|", "Welcome to Karla's Trad|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradi|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradin|", "Welcome to Karla's Trading|", "Welcome to Karla's Trading", "Welcome to Karla's Trading|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradin|", "Welcome to Karla's Tradi|", "Welcome to Karla's Trad|", "Welcome to Karla's Tra|", "Welcome to Karla's Tr|", "Welcome to Karla's T|", "Welcome to Karla's |", "Welcome to Karla's|", "Welcome to Karla'|", "Welcome to Karla|", "Welcome to Karl|", "Welcome to Kar|", "Welcome to Ka|", "Welcome to K|", "Welcome to |", "Welcome t|", "Welcome |", "Welcome|", "Welcom|", "Welco|", "Welc|", "Wel|", "We|", "W|", "|"];
  var counter = 0;
  var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
  var setInt = setInterval(change, 250);

  function change() {
    elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
    counter++;
    console.log('c:'+counter +'t:'+text.length);
    if (counter == text.length) {
      console.log('clear');
      clearInterval(setInt);
    }
  }
</script>
```